# Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, xdebug

Can help pls)
Have a k8s cluster, on cluster running pod with 3 docker container.
When i try uploda file have the next error:

```
| metrics time="2021-11-12T10:09:53Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :9253 with path /metrics"                                                                                                                │
│ metrics time="2021-11-12T10:39:57Z" level=error msg="Inconsistent active and idle processes reported. Set `--fix-process-count` to have this calculated by php-fpm_exporter instead."                           │
│ metrics time="2021-11-12T12:28:17Z" level=error msg="Inconsistent active and idle processes reported. Set `--fix-process-count` to have this calculated by php-fpm_exporter instead."                           │
│ proxysql 2021-11-12 16:23:30 MySQL_Thread.cpp:4385:process_all_sessions(): [WARNING] Closing unhealthy client connection localhost:0                                                                            │
│ proxysql 2021-11-12 16:23:31 MySQL_Thread.cpp:4385:process_all_sessions(): [WARNING] Closing unhealthy client connection localhost:0                                                                            │
│ app NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(                                       │
│ app NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(                                       │
│ app NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(                                       │
│ app NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(                                       │
│ app NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(                                       │
│ nginx 2021/11/12 16:23:37 [error] 7#7: *8314 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xde │
│ proxysql 2021-11-12 16:23:40 MySQL_Thread.cpp:4385:process_all_sessions(): [WARNING] Closing unhealthy client connection localhost:0                                                                            │
│ proxysql 2021-11-12 16:23:41 MySQL_Thread.cpp:4385:process_all_sessions(): [WARNING] Closing unhealthy client connection localhost:0                                                                            │
│ app NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(                                       │
│ app NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(                                       │
│ app NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(                                       │
│ nginx 2021/11/12 16:23:47 [error] 7#7: *8314 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xde │
│ proxysql 2021-11-12 16:23:50 MySQL_Thread.cpp:4385:process_all_sessions(): [WARNING] Closing unhealthy client connection localhost:0                                                                            │
│ proxysql 2021-11-12 16:23:51 MySQL_Thread.cpp:4385:process_all_sessions(): [WARNING] Closing unhealthy client connection localhost:0                                                                            │
│ proxysql 2021-11-12 16:24:00 MySQL_Thread.cpp:4385:process_all_sessions(): [WARNING] Closing unhealthy client connection localhost:0                                                                            │
│ proxysql 2021-11-12 16:24:01 MySQL_Thread.cpp:4385:process_all_sessions(): [WARNING] Closing unhealthy client connection localhost:0                                                                            │
│ app NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(                                       │
│ app NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(                                       │
│ app NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(                                       │
│ nginx 2021/11/12 16:24:08 [error] 7#7: *8314 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xde │
│ proxysql 2021-11-12 16:24:10 MySQL_Thread.cpp:4385:process_all_sessions(): [WARNING] Closing unhealthy client connection localhost:0                                                                            │
│ proxysql 2021-11-12 16:24:11 MySQL_Thread.cpp:4385:process_all_sessions(): [WARNING] Closing unhealthy client connection localhost:0                                                                            │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: What is your question here? That you get the message, or that debugging does not work?

Comment: I cannot upload file to bucket in gcloud, infinite download duting upload, 1% and stop, in logs of k8s message which i post

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok, np. I have ks8 cluster,with namespace stage, in namespace stage i have pod with 3 containers. 1) Container - app; 2) container - nginx; 3) container - sql;
I try upload file in google bucket and have a pack of errors higher. Can you pls say what information you need?

Comment: need help with xdebug cannot connect to debugging client, my conf:
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal